# Are CreateEntityAdapter and normalizr compatible by default?- SelectId always undefined

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to add normalized records from normalizr.normalize to the redux store.
In my slice file I am trying to use createEntityAdapter.
When I dispatch my action to the store it will always fail as the default SelectId function returns undefined. Is it necessary to write a custom selectId function for this case?

Normalized data will be in object format

```
{
  "1":{
     key:value,
     ...
     id:"1"
  }
...
}`
```

Comment: Resolved thanks to @markerikson for the sanity check. The problem was that even though the normalized data contained 2 different entities (leave,workallocation) I was asking my leave slice to just add the payload. Changing my add reducer in the leave slice to just act on the leave entity solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createEntityAdapter` assumes by default that each item has an `id` field.  If your data does actually have an `id` field, no `selectId` option is needed - it *should* work with that data as-is.